# Lambda function doesn't trigger in Cognito post confirmation

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I used AWS amplify to export user signup info to Cognito, and new users are shown correctly in the Cognito user pool, then I created a Lambda function to transfer user details from Cognito to DynamoDB and set this Lambda function as the post confirmation trigger of the Cognito user pool, but user still cannot be transferred to DynamoDB.
the lambda function works well so I think it's the problem of Cognito or amplify or maybe role access. but I have set lambda function role has all Cognito access.

My lambda function:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ddb = new aws.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(event);

    let date = new Date();

    const tableName = process.env.TABLE_NAME;
    const region = process.env.REGION;
  
    
    console.log("table=" + tableName + " -- region=" + region);

    aws.config.update({region: region});
    

    // If the required parameters are present, proceed
    if (event.request.userAttributes.sub) {

        // -- Write data to DDB
        let ddbParams = {
            Item: {
                'sub': {S: event.request.userAttributes.sub},
                'given_name': {S: event.request.userAttributes.given_name},
                'family_name': {S: event.request.userAttributes.family_name},
                'email': {S: event.request.userAttributes.email},
                'email_verified': {S: event.request.userAttributes.email_verified},
                'teamName': {S: event.request.userAttributes.teamName},
                'ifManager': {S: event.request.userAttributes.if_you_are_a_manager},
                'createdAt': {S: date.toISOString()},
            },
            TableName: tableName
        };
        console.log(ddbParams)

        // Call DynamoDB
        try {
            await ddb.putItem(ddbParams).promise()
            console.log("Success");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        }

        console.log("Success: Everything executed correctly");
        context.done(null, event);

    } else {
        // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
        console.log("Error: Nothing was written to DDB or SQS");
        context.done(null, event);
    }
};
```

My amplify file:

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './amplifyConfig';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
const formFields = {
    signUp: {
      username: {
        order:1,
        labelHidden: false,
        label:'Email:',
        placeholder: 'Enter your email',
        isRequired: true,
      },
      given_name: {
        order: 2,
        label: 'First name:',
        placeholder: 'Enter your first name',
        isRequired: true,
  
      },
      family_name: {
        order: 3,
        label: 'Last name:',
        placeholder: 'Enter your last name',
        isRequired: true,
      },
      'custom:teamName':{
        order:4,
        label: 'Team name:',
        placeholder: 'Enter your team name',
        isRequired: true,
      },
      'custom:if_you_are_a_manager':{
        order:5,
        label: 'Are you a manager (Yes/No)?',
        placeholder: 'Please type Yes or No',
        isRequired: true,
      },
      password: {
        order: 6
      },
      confirm_password: {
        order: 7
      }
    },
  
  }
export default function AmplifyAuth() {
  return (
    <Authenticator formFields={formFields}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.attributes.given_name}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the lambda logs?

Comment: From the lambda logs I can see that the Cognito post confirmation is not triggered.

Comment: How to make sure post confirmation handler has enough permission to access dynamodb instance? I have set another cognito hosted UI for authentication and set post confirmation lambda function and it worked. The reason I gave up this solution is that cognito hosted ui doesn't support custom attribute in signup form.

Comment: @Lynn as you have mentioned that Lambda is not being triggered, I would suggest you to check following 2 points first. 
1. Have you configured the trigger in Cognito ? If not please refer the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers-using-lambda) and configure that first. 
2. We should test this from a new user sign up, as Cognito invoke the Post Confirmation trigger just after a new user is confirmed.

Comment: @SampathDilhan I am checking why postconfirmation is not being called and then I read your comment and I just got the bug! Thank you so much.